# 3D archery course in croatia with ocean view

Tags: archery, 3d-archery

I'm searching for a 3D archery course in Croatia. It has to fulfill following requirements:

- It has to be open for public
- It should be located in range of the ocean
  approx. 30 minutes to walk to the beach

Bonus requirement:

- As a few people will join my vacation, it may come in handy if you can rent equipment there

Comment: Possibly better for Travel?

Comment: @Liam Wouldn't say so since "track searching questions" are ontopic. A 3D archery course isn't really different from a hiking trail. Like e.g. http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/good-2-day-alpine-hike-near-liezen-austria

Comment: It's a valid point...!

Comment: Hi OddDeer! I know nothing about archery, or 3D archery, so I can't really help. I did find a [Croation Division](http://hdhiaa.net/members/croatia-h3dss/) of the International Archery Association. 3D archery seems common with that Association, so maybe they can help you. I hope so!